# 4.15.0-43 is not booting?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, nvidia, crash

Yesterday my computer suddenly crashed. Since then the boot will hang on a purple blank screen when trying to boot with default 4.15.0-43.   However, if I start the Grub Menu and select 4.15.0-42 everything works fine. What is the problem?

Here is my hardware:

- Intel Core i7 7700K 4x 4.20GHz
- MSI Z370-A PRO Intel Z370
- 32GB DDR4-2400 DIMM
- 8GB MSI GeForce GTX 1070
- 1000GB Samsung 860 SSD

This is my system log file:

```
08:23:12 kernel: Syncing filesystems and block devices.
08:23:12 kernel: systemd-shutdow: 39 output lines suppressed due to ratelimiting
08:22:45 kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1548228165.851:10): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=922 comm="apparmor_parser"
08:22:45 kernel: FAT-fs (sdd1): IO charset iso8859-1 not found
08:22:45 kernel: Adding 2097148k swap on /swapfile.  Priority:-2 extents:6 across:2260988k SSFS
08:22:45 kernel: random: 7 urandom warning(s) missed due to ratelimiting
08:22:44 kernel: EXT4-fs (sdd2): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
08:22:44 kernel: Listening on Journal Audit Socket.
08:22:44 kernel: Created slice system-systemd\x2dfsck.slice.
08:22:44 kernel: Listening on /dev/initctl Compatibility Named Pipe.
08:22:44 kernel: Created slice System Slice.
08:22:44 kernel: Set hostname to <adam-MS-7A63>.
08:22:44 kernel: Detected architecture x86-64.
08:22:44 kernel: systemd 237 running in system mode. (+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ +LZ4 +SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD -IDN2 +IDN -PCRE2 default-hierarchy=hybrid)
08:22:44 kernel: Failed to insert module 'autofs4': No such file or directory
08:22:44 kernel: RTC configured in localtime, applying delta of 60 minutes to system time.
08:22:44 kernel: sd 6:0:0:3: [sdh] Attached SCSI removable disk
08:22:44 kernel: scsi 6:0:0:3: Direct-Access     Generic- xD-Picture       1.02 PQ: 0 ANSI: 4
08:22:44 kernel: EXT4-fs (sdd2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
08:22:44 kernel: Btrfs loaded, crc32c=crc32c-intel
08:22:44 kernel: hid-generic 0003:046D:C326.0004: input,hiddev0,hidraw3: USB HID v1.10 Device [Logitech USB Keyboard] on usb-0000:00:14.0-13.2/input1
08:22:44 kernel: async_tx: api initialized (async)
08:22:44 kernel: xor: automatically using best checksumming function   avx       
08:22:44 kernel: raid6: using avx2x2 recovery algorithm
08:22:44 kernel: input: Logitech USB Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-13/1-13.2/1-13.2:1.1/0003:046D:C326.0004/input/input6
08:22:44 kernel: hid-generic 0003:046D:C326.0003: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [Logitech USB Keyboard] on usb-0000:00:14.0-13.2/input0
08:22:44 kernel: raid6: avx2x2   xor() 23566 MB/s
08:22:44 kernel: input: Logitech USB Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-13/1-13.2/1-13.2:1.0/0003:046D:C326.0003/input/input5
08:22:44 kernel: usb 1-13.2: Manufacturer: Logitech
08:22:44 kernel: raid6: avx2x2   gen() 38916 MB/s
08:22:44 kernel: usb 1-13.2: new low-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
08:22:44 kernel: raid6: avx2x1   gen() 31611 MB/s
08:22:44 kernel: hid-generic 0003:1532:0029.0002: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [Razer Razer DeathAdder] on usb-0000:00:14.0-13.1/input0
08:22:44 kernel: input: Razer Razer DeathAdder as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-13/1-13.1/1-13.1:1.0/0003:1532:0029.0002/input/input4
08:22:44 kernel: usb 1-13.1: Manufacturer: Razer
08:22:44 kernel: raid6: sse2x4   gen() 22657 MB/s
08:22:44 kernel: usb 1-13.1: new full-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
08:22:44 kernel: raid6: sse2x2   gen() 19574 MB/s
08:22:44 kernel: hid-generic 0003:046D:0A45.0001: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.00 Device [Logitech Logitech USB Headset] on usb-0000:00:14.0-5/input3
08:22:44 kernel: input: Logitech Logitech USB Headset as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5/1-5:1.3/0003:046D:0A45.0001/input/input3
08:22:44 kernel: usbhid: USB HID core driver
08:22:44 kernel: usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
08:22:44 kernel: scsi host6: usb-storage 1-12:1.0
08:22:44 kernel: usb-storage 1-12:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
08:22:44 kernel: hidraw: raw HID events driver (C) Jiri Kosina
08:22:44 kernel: hub 1-13:1.0: 4 ports detected
08:22:44 kernel: usb 1-13: Manufacturer: GenesysLogic
08:22:44 kernel: e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 enp0s31f6: renamed from eth0
08:22:44 kernel: random: systemd-udevd: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read)
08:22:44 kernel: e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 eth0: MAC: 12, PHY: 12, PBA No: FFFFFF-0FF
08:22:44 kernel: random: fast init done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had a similar problem with systemd and I solved it recompiling the kernel.
You can also think to upgrade kernel.

Comment: Nice updating to 4.20.3-042003-generic works just fine. Thank you!